# How to exclude JavaScript code in node_module when using Reactive Native Debugger

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger

I am new to React-Native development. I found out two issues that are related to debugging react-native code with React Native Debugger Tools.

1. The source code to be debugged is not organized in a folder structure, instead, The source code is listed in the same folder.
2. The vendor code (node_modules) also included in the source panel.

Anyway, it is not convenient to debug the code and inefficient.

[image]